# Mounting React Components to The Client

Tags: reactjs, render

I'm relatively new to React and I'm about to mount my first react component, but when I go to render the code it doesn't mount. Can anyone help me here?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Hello extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <h1>Hello California</h1>   
            </div>
        );
    }
}
React.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do two things to render this component

1) ReactDOM is the library that will render the component to the bind html Element, so first import ReactDom from the 'react-dom' package

2) Then Call render method of ReactDOM

You only need to call reatDOM.render once method outside the class component

Here's the complete code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Hello extends Component{
    render() {
     return (
         <div>
         <h1>Hello California</h1>   
         </div>
    );
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`ReactDOM.render()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render) to render a React element into the DOM in the supplied container (`Hello`).

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

// all codes you have

ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: What do you mean by supplied container? I'm new to React; can you please explain?

Comment: @Mark Sure thing. I mentioned it in bracket `Hello`. `render` method from `ReactDOM` is used to attached a React component to the browser DOM. I would also suggest to read [react official](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html) guide page by page to get comfortable with React concepts.

Comment: I just modified the code and it still doesn't work? The code looks as follows:

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

    class Hello extends Component{
     ReactDOM.render() {
      return (
       <div>
       <h1>Hello California</h1> 
       </div>
      );
     }
    }

ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById("root"));

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your dom with the id `root`?

Comment: @Mark Did you open the links I gave to you? Check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/nn5omrkqqp) .. Did you add the html with id root, like `<div id="root"></div>` ?

Comment: Yes, the index.html file has the div with an id of "root".

Comment: Yes, I just took a look and it's working in codesandbox. I think the problem might be the way I configured the json and webpack files. I'm following along with a book tutorial and the book might be outdated. It was released in 2015, but when I set-up the react files with the 2018 set-up and use export default app or export default Hello it works perfectly. I'll keep reading and hopefully I'll get it soon. Thanks for all the help!